# Не могу поместить параграф под заголовок на html, css

Tags: html, css, текст

Вот есть у меня код на хтмл

```css
/*Скачивание приложения*/

.download {
  display: flex;
}

.download img {
  margin-top: 10vh;
  margin-left: 2vh;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
}

.download h1 {
  margin-top: 20vh;
  margin-left: 8vh;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.download__text {
  display: flex;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="download">
  <img src="mobile.svg">
  <h1>Бесплатное приложения PrimeCraft</h1>
</div>
<p class="download__text">Когда-то тут будет какой-то прикольный текст но пока что мне лень его придумывать, надеюсь ты хотябы мне поможешь его придумать :)</p>
```

Я хотел бы поместить параграф под заголовок (Бесплатное приложения PrimeCraft)

Но к сожалению у меня получилось только это, я и туториалы смотрел но ничего не помогло, помогите мне пожалуйста

[image]

Comment: Так в коде HTML поместите Ваш параграф `p` сразу же после заголовка `h1` внутрь тэга `div`. Так как `div` по умолчанию - блочный элемент, то он занимает всю ширину Вашей строки и параграф вынужден разместиться под картинкой. Только оберните ещё заголовок и параграф в отдельный `div`, чтобы они стали одним flex-элементом и разместились справа от картинки

Answer (score 2):

Оберните весь текст вместе с заголовком в один контейнер:

```css
/*Скачивание приложения*/
.download {
    display: flex;
}

.download img {
    margin-top: 10vh;
    margin-left: 2vh;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
}

.download h1 {
    margin-top: 20vh;
    margin-left: 8vh;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.download__text {
    display: flex;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="download">
  <img src="mobile.svg">
  <div class="download__text-container">
     <h1>Бесплатное приложения PrimeCraft</h1>
      <p class="download__text">Когда-то тут будет какой-то прикольный текст но пока что мне лень его придумывать, надеюсь ты хотябы мне поможешь его придумать :)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том что тэг `<p>` находится за "контейнером" , для того что бы параграф был под заголовком нужно поместить его в контейнер непосредственно под заголовок `<h1>`:

```
<div class="download">
  <img src="mobile.svg">
  <div class="download__text-container">
     <h1>Бесплатное приложения PrimeCraft</h1>
      <p class="download__text">Когда-то тут будет какой-то прикольный текст но пока 
       что мне лень его придумывать, надеюсь ты хотябы мне поможешь его придумать :) 
       </p>
  </div>
</div>
```